# How to make a transparent ground in OSMBuildings.js?

Tags: javascript

I need to have my own color as a background or have it transparent, can't neither change not set it to transparent. https://osmbuildings.org/developer/

There is a `options.backgroundColor` option but it doesn't change anything. Need to get rid of background and have only buildings rendered in canvas.

Comment: Maybe this library needs some more work on it, I've tested and also not getting any results when changing `backgroundColor` nor `style` nor `style.color`, only got results when changed `fogColor` which doesn't make big sense :)

Comment: @codtex Thanks for the info, very helpful. I thought i do something wrong (it seems to me as well that it's not ready for usage yet.